# Developing Qt apps for LynxOS 7.0

Tags: qt, qt-creator, lynxos

I am new to LynxOS can any one give some ideas/suggestions for below questions:

1. Which Qt version can be used to develop applications for LynxOs 7.0.
2. Proper documentation to build and setup Qt (Qt creator, Qt kits : Compiler etc) for LynxOS 7.0.